# Boolean values in Qgis report

Tags: qgis, reports

I am building a report in QGIS that handels a layer with quite a large attribute table (around 200 attributes). But most of the attributes are boolean values and I only need (want to display) 'true' values in my report.

Is there a way, possibly with expression builder, to filter for boolean 'true' values?

EDIT:

[image]

This is a section of the attribute table, and i only want to display the attributes with 'true', but that differs from case to case, so i have to add all of them to the report, and want to filter them while generating the report.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot please for a better comprehension ?